# How to generate random hex string in javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

How to generate a random string containing only hex characters (0123456789abcdef) of a given length?

Answer (score 70):

Short alternative using spread operator and `.map()`

---

#### Demo 1

```js
const genRanHex = size => [...Array(size)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16)).join('');

console.log(genRanHex(6));
console.log(genRanHex(12));
console.log(genRanHex(3));
```

---

1. Pass in a number (`size`) for the length of the returned string.
2. Define an empty array (`result`) and an array of strings in the range of `[0-9]` and `[a-f]` (`hexRef`).
3. On each iteration of a `for` loop, generate a random number 0 to 15 and use it as the index of the value from the array of strings from step 2 (`hexRef`) -- then `push()` the value to the empty array from step 2 (`result`).
4. Return the array (`result`) as a `join('')`ed string.

---

#### Demo 2

```js
const getRanHex = size => {
  let result = [];
  let hexRef = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

  for (let n = 0; n < size; n++) {
    result.push(hexRef[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]);
  }
  return result.join('');
}

console.log(getRanHex(6));
console.log(getRanHex(12));
console.log(getRanHex(3));
```

Comment: What are the chances that it cannot be unique when 2 clients generate

Comment: @Naga not safe enough. I ended up creating a miro-service to keep track of 16 char hex strings across clients

Answer (score 48):

### NodeJS Users

You can use [randomBytes](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) available in the `crypto` module, to generate cryptographically strong pseudorandom data of a given size. And you can easily convert it to hex.

```js
import crypto from "crypto";

const randomString = crypto.randomBytes(8).toString("hex");

console.log(randomString)  // ee48d32e6c724c4d
```

The above code snippet generates a random 8-bytes hex number, you can manipulate the length as you wish.

Answer (score 9):

There are a few ways. One way is to just pull from a predefined string:

```
function genHexString(len) {
    const hex = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    let output = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        output += hex.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length));
    }
    return output;
}
```

The other way is to append a random number between 0 and 15 converted to hex with toString:

```
function genHexString(len) {
    let output = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        output += (Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)).toString(16);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a hexa number 0xfffff to random a hex string

```
getHexaNumb() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16).padEnd(6, "0")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This securely generates a 32-byte random string and encodes it as hex (64 characters).

```js
Array.from(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(32)))
    .map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
```

Long version:

```js
function generateRandomHexString(numBytes) {
    const bytes = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(numBytes));
    const array = Array.from(bytes);
    const hexPairs = array.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'));
    return hexPairs.join('')
}
```

Comment: The length of the returned string will be `numBytes * 2`

Comment: `crypto.getRandomValues` doesn’t exist until Node 19 so if you need your code to run in the browser and Node, this way is a real pain.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use lodash library here is the code snippet to generate a 16 chars string:

```
let randomString = _.times(16, () => (Math.random()*0xF<<0).toString(16)).join('');
```

Comment: and if you want only 4 digits I think you can change that first 16 to 4.

Answer (score 2):

Length of the array is the length of the random string.

```js
const randomHex = Array.from({ length: 32 }, () => "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16))).join('');
console.log(randomHex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that avoids building one digit at a time; it's probably only suitable for short lengths.

```
function genHexString(len) {
    const str = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(16, len)).toString(16);
    return "0".repeat(len - str.length) + str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for lengths up to 13:

```js
randomHex = length => (
        '0'.repeat(length) 
        + Math.floor((Math.random() * 16 ** length))
        .toString(16)
    ).slice(-length);

console.log(randomHex(4));
console.log(randomHex(6));
console.log(randomHex(13));
console.log(randomHex(20));
```

Answer (score 0):

Up to 7 characters may be quickly taken from one Math.random() call (A):

```js
const halfBytesIn35 = 7 // = 3.5 bytes
const byte35 = Math.pow(16, halfBytesIn35)
const bytes35 = () => ((Math.random() * byte35) | 0).toString(16).padStart(halfBytesIn35,'0')
console.log('A: ' + bytes35())

const bytes65 = len => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(16, len*2)).toString(16).padStart(len,'0')
console.log('B: ' + bytes65(6))

function moreBytes (len) {
  len *= 2; // alternative: len <<= 1 if you do not use half bytes. This might allow optimizations based on len always being an Integer then.
  let builder = "";
  while (len > 0) {
    builder += bytes35()
    len -= 7
  }
  return builder.slice(0,len)
}
console.log('C: ' + moreBytes(16))
```

Store the Math.pow constant if you plan to use this with high frequency.

An 8th letter overflows into the sign bit in the binary floor.

You can reach up to 13 characters from one call by using Math.floor instead (B) or even loop the generator for an arbitrary length (C).

Note that this could be used to *define* premature optimization. If your bottleneck really is the creation of Random Numbers consider using LUTs. This is common if you are developing for embedded. (And in this case somehow got stuck using javascript, but do not have the timebuget to generate random Numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Using for Loop, charAt and Math.random

```
let result = "";
let hexChar = "0123456789abcdef";
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  result += hexChar.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * hexChar.length));
}
console.log(`#${result}`);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using Math.random, you can do 13 characters at a time in a convenient way. If you want an arbitrary length string, you can still do it with a "one-liner":

```
const makeRandomHexString = (length: number) =>
  Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(length / 13) })
    .map(() =>
      Math.floor(Math.random() * (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / 2))
        .toString(16)
        .padStart(13, '0')
    )
    .join('')
    .substring(0, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified program to generate random hexadecimal Colour code:

```js
let items = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
let item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
console.log(item);

let random = Math.random().toString().slice(2, 6);
console.log(`#${item}${random}${item}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let generateMacAdd = (function () {
    let hexas = '0123456789ABCDEF'
    let storeMac = []
    let i = 0
    do {
        let random1st = hexas.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * hexas.length))
        let random2nd = hexas.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * hexas.length))
        storeMac.push(random1st + random2nd)
        i++
    } while (i <= 6)
    return storeMac.join(':')
})()
console.log(generateMacAdd);       //will generate a formatted mac address
```

> I use self invoking function here so you can just call the variable
> w/o any arguments
>
> I also use do while here, just for my own convenience, you can do
> any kind of loop depends what you're comfortable

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate a `6-digit Hex code` for yourself with this function that I wrote here

```js
function generateRandomHex(){
  let result = '';
  const characters = 'ABCDEF123456789';
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
}
```

If you want a function that takes the value from the input, you can use the following function

```js
function generateRandomHex(length){
  let result = '';
  const characters = 'ABCDEF123456789';
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can make a unique random hex value using Date class.

```js
const makeSize = 2
const uniqueHexValue = [...Array(makeSize)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * new Date().valueOf()).toString(16)).join("")
```

Answer (score -1):

On modern browsers there is also the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API). It also allows to generate (cryptographically strong) random values, similar to what `node:crypto` does:

```js
const randomHex = (bytes = 8) => {
  // fill typed array with random numbers
  // from 0..255 per entry
  const array = new Uint8Array(bytes)
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(array)

  // wrap to array and convert numbers to hex
  // then join to single string
  return [...array]
    .map(n => n.toString(16))
    .join('')
}
```

### examples usage

```js
console.debug(randomHex(2)) // 47be
console.debug(randomHex(4)) // 414c34a2
console.debug(randomHex(8)) // 53f5d393e13bd86
```

### Resources

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues