# Get some different random elements from one array, (without setting a different variable each time)

Tags: javascript

I want get random HEX color.
that is my code (JavaScript):

```
 let colors = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','A','B','C','D','E','F']; 
 let random = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
 
 console.log(`#${random}${random}${random}${random}${random}${random}`);
```

but it returns the same element whenever I call a variable (for exam. "#cccccc", "#999999"..).

Do I have to set the variable 6 times, or there is a shorter way?

any feedback will help me.(I am an absolute beginner with programming)

Comment: so you have to generate a new random  number each time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58325771/how-to-generate-random-hex-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this line:

```
let random = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```

You might think that you are stating: "This is how I want a random value".

That's not how it's happening. You are fetching a random color once, and then assigning it to the variable `random`.

If you want it to be a generation rule, you would have to make `random` a function, not a variable:

```
function random() {
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

 console.log(`#${random()}${random()}${random()}${random()}${random()}${random()}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate, try this:

```js
let colors = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','A','B','C','D','E','F']; 
let digits = 10;
let result = "#";

for(i = 0; i < digits; i++){
    result += colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your code is making the variable `random`, but never changing it. So, when you log it, it uses the same letter or number over and over again. Below is a solution.

```js
function randomHex() {
  let colors = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
  let hex = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    hex += colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }
  return hex;
}
console.log(randomHex())
```

Answer (score 0):

`random` is initialised (assigned a value) once. To continually re-initialise `random`, you could use a `for loop`. The block (`{}`) of a `for loop` is re-initialised each time you iterate (go through) the loop. For example:

```js
function randomHex() {

let colors = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','A','B','C','D','E','F']; 

symbolArray = []

for (let counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++) {
    let randomSymbol = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    symbolArray.push(randomSymbol)
}

let hexNumbers = symbolArray.join('');

console.log('#' + hexNumbers);
}

randomHex();
randomHex();
randomHex();
```