# How can I create a unique code in an operation that is running in two loops?

Tags: javascript, html

I create a function that get two value(Number) and builds a table based on it;These two are the same value as the row and column of the table.
For each row that create an `tr`  and For each column that create an `td` and an `input` inside that.

I want to send that information to the backend and i need the unique code for each name attribute of `input`

```
<section id="table">
                <form class="w-100" action="/">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-center align-items-center p-4">
                            column: <input onkeyup="table_creator()" onchange="table_creator()" name="column" class="ml-2" id="column" type="number">
                            row: <input onkeyup="table_creator()" onchange="table_creator()" name="row" id="row" type="number">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            
                                <table  class="table table-striped">
                                    <tbody id="am_table_tb"></tbody>
                                </table>
                                <input class="btn btn-outline-success shadow-0" type="submit" value="create">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
</section>
```

JavaScript :

```
function table_creator() {
  column = document.getElementById("column").value;
  row = document.getElementById("row").value;
  var tbody = document.getElementById("am_table_tb");
  tbody.innerHTML= '';
  if (column != "" && row != "") {
    if (row != "" && row != 0) {
      for (var r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        if (column != "") {
          for (var c = 0; c < column; c++) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "text");
            input.setAttribute("name", "uniqu_code");
            tr.appendChild(td);
            td.appendChild(input);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to create a unique code that mixture of number and text;We can get the number of inputs made ​​in the table by multiplying the column and row.So we can use zero to the number obtained for each attribute of `input`.
How can i do it?

Comment: You can also just use your `r` and `c` variables in the loops: `input.setAttribute("name", "uniqu_code_" + r + "_" + c);`

Comment: In addition to @HanletEscaño's comment, you can use the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58325771/how-to-generate-random-hex-string-in-javascript to generate a truly unique code, where `len` is the length of the digits you want for the unique code.

Comment: I think simply you have to do what @hanlet-escaño said for title of your question. but it make the server-side variables NOT able to handle easy. Usually for these kind of targets you better to use an array name and also `multidimensional array name`. So set name like this: `input.setAttribute("name", "cell["+r+"][]");`
With this, you can handle the variables by calling them like `cell[0][1]` in your server.