# (proper) Randomization in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So there's this image uploading service called *LightShot*. You can easily go to any image on there with "prnt.sc/" and a 6-digit sequence of letters & numbers.

I thought it would be cool to program some code that gives you a random link to the site. Here's the code:

```js
function func() {
    let x = 'https://prnt.sc/';
    let a = 1;
    let b = '';

    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        a = Math.floor(Math.random(16));
        console.log(a);
        if (a = 10) {
            b += 'a';
        } else if (a = 16) {
            b += 'a';
        } else if (a = 12) {
            b += 'c';
        } else if (a = 11) {
            b += 'b';
        } else if (a = 13) {
            b += 'd';
        } else if (a = 14) {
            b += 'e';
        } else if (a = 15) {
            b += 'f';
        } else { 
            b += a.toString();
        }
    } x += b;
    console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="./sketch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick='func()'>Go</button>
</body>

</html>
```

***Meanwhile, in the console...***

> ➏ 0 
> (***insert the rest here***)/aaaaaa

Well, maybe it's something to do with the block of *IF* statements or the *toString()* function, but I don't know:

1. How it got *0* 6 out of 6 times,
2. How it got all *A*'s out of those zeros.

If someone could could fix this, please let me know.

Comment: you can use a `switch`-statement instead of repeating `if/else`-statements. Also you can randomize out of an array.

Comment: Comparisons are done using `==` or `===`

Comment: `Math.random()` does not accept a parameter `Math.random(16)` doesn't do anything special, still returns a number in the range [0,1). And if you round it down, you always get a zero.

Comment: You need this: `Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 << 24)).toString(16).padStart(6, '0')`

Comment: @ChrisG Ok, but where?

Comment: Seeing as it [doesn't appear to be bound to just hexadecimal characters](https://prnt.sc/qwerty), I would think you could just [utilize this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1349426/231316), adjusting the alphabet for no upper case

Comment: You might want to consider using a JSON that way instead of checking the value of a, you can just look up the value of a then if it is undefined, then you know it's not in the JSON and add the number instead. This also makes it easier to add more options

Comment: This is a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58325771/how-to-generate-random-hex-string-in-javascript

Comment: What I posted is an expression that generates a random six digit hex number. You can assign it to a constant or just add it to the rest of the URL.

Comment: @CharlieCiampa  A JSON? What does JSON have to do with generating a random hex string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the logical of random is important, you are mistake

you replace blow

```
a = Math.floor(Math.random(16));
```

with

```
a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 7);
```

and replace "=" with "==="

total fix

```
function func() {
  let x = "https://prnt.sc/";
  let a = 1;
  let b = "";

  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 10);
    console.log(a);
    if (a === 10) {
      b += "a";
    } else if (a === 16) {
      b += "a";
    } else if (a === 12) {
      b += "c";
    } else if (a === 11) {
      b += "b";
    } else if (a === 13) {
      b += "d";
    } else if (a === 14) {
      b += "e";
    } else if (a === 15) {
      b += "f";
    } else {
      b += a.toString();
    }
    console.log(b);
  }
  x += b;
  console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It's clearly not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the number or letter from an array as shown below and run the randomizer 6 times.

First you have to define a variable with an array that includes all the possibilies (0, 1, 3 ... 8, 9, A, B, ... E, F):
`var random = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];`

Then you can use the `random()`-function to run a choice out fo that array:
`random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];`

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var string = ""
  var random = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    var number = random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];   
    string += number;
  }
  console.log(string);
});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: `let hex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);` would seem better....